# Need to use xslt transformation for xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am very new to xslt and after multiple retries I am not able to proceed from here. The current xslt I have prepared is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="action">
<action> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   <attribute name="phase" value="new" />
</action>    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which changes this input xml :

```
<root>
<attribute name="phases">
<tag>
  <entryMap name="startphase">
    <action>
      <type>Some type</type>
      <attribute name="first" value="abc" />
    </action>
  </entryMap>
</tag>
</attribute>
</root>
```

to this output xml (adds `<attribute name="phase" value="new"/>` inside `<action>` and after `<type>`):

```
<root>
<attribute name="phases">
  <tag>
     <entryMap name="startphase">
        <action>
           <type>Some type</type>
           <attribute name="first" value="abc"/>
           <attribute name="phase" value="new"/>
        </action>
     </entryMap>
  </tag>
</attribute>
</root>
```

My xml file can change and have multiple phases and so I need to make changes in the xslt file to transform this example input xml :

```
<root>
<attribute name="phases">
    <tag>
      <entryMap name="startphase">
        <action>
          <type>Some type</type>
          <attribute name="first" value="abc" />
        </action>
      </entryMap>
    </tag>
</attribute>
<attribute name="phases">
    <tag>
      <entryMap name="midphase">
        <action>
          <type>Some other type</type>
          <attribute name="second" value="def" />
        </action>
      </entryMap>
    </tag>
</attribute>
<attribute name="phases">
    <tag>
      <entryMap name="endphase">
        <action>
          <type>Other type</type>
          <attribute name="third" value="ghi" />
        </action>
      </entryMap>
    </tag>
</attribute>
</root>
```

to this output file :

```
<root>
   <attribute name="phases">
      <tag>
         <entryMap name="startphase">
            <action>
               <type>Some type</type>
               <attribute name="first" value="abc"/>
               <attribute name="phase" value="startphase"/>
            </action>
         </entryMap>
      </tag>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="phases">
      <tag>
         <entryMap name="midphase">
            <action>
               <type>Some other type</type>
               <attribute name="second" value="def"/>
               <attribute name="phase" value="midphase"/>
            </action>
         </entryMap>
      </tag>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="phases">
      <tag>
         <entryMap name="endphase">
            <action>
               <type>Other type</type>
               <attribute name="third" value="ghi"/>
               <attribute name="phase" value="endphase"/>
            </action>
         </entryMap>
      </tag>
   </attribute>
</root>
```

That is, I need to add `<attribute name="phase" value="entryMap name value"/>`to every phase and the value attribute should contain the value of entryMap name attribute value.

I have tried and gone through many links and tutorials but I am still not able to achieve this. I will be very, very grateful if someone could help me with this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="action">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <attribute name="phase" value="{../@name}"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand how this works, read about [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates) and [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev).

---

### Added:

> is there any way by which the `<attribute name="phase" value="entryMap name value"/>` is added right after the `<type></type>` tag?

You could do it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <attribute name="phase" value="{../../@name}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This worked for me in adding the phase and value attributes!! Thank you so much!! Just wanted to ask, is there any way by which the `<attribute name="phase" value="entryMap name value"/>`  is added right after the `<type></type>` tag? I read somewhere that if we add a template to <type> first using something like `<xsl:apply-templates select="type"/>` then it is achievable. But I didn't get the expected output using this. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.